# How to center and align things in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere

One thing I always face trouble with is aligning things in Premiere Pro.

In Photoshop, if you have an image you can just align it with align tools. If you want to align multiple things, you group them and align them in left, right or center etc.

I want to achieve something like that with videos.

For example these 3 clips are placed randomly with a guess that they are visually aligned. But they aren't perfect. I just adjusted them manually.

[image]

So how can I a) select those 3 clips and align them horizontally (marked by yellow)? b) Align the right most 2 clips horizontally to each other (marked by green)?

Right now all things seem aligned but I did hit and trials and it took a lot of effort.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is usually not done in Premiere, since it involves motion-graphics that are way easier done in After-Effects.

If you have to do this in Premiere though, the only way to make sure that - the two smaller pictures for example - align perfectly on their vertical axis is to take a look at their position and put in the same value for the x-axis (the first value).

Comment: Florian Claaßen got it. But in After Effects videos of high resolution (4K) run very slowly even in lowest settings, when compared to Premiere Pro. Isn't it?

Comment: There should be no difference between performance, if you have the same settings. You can drop the viewport quality to half, quarter or eighth same as with premiere, you should enable hardware acceleration and CUDA if you're using windows with Nvidia, you should assign a proper amount of RAM (16GB is generally neat), and clear the cache regularly (edit -> purge -> purge all). If you do all that, After-Effects might even be faster and more stable than the buggy Premiere.

Comment: I am using same PC for both. But I've observed for 1080p videos there are not major performance differences. But when videos have high data (4K), After Effects video play is very laggy as compared to premiere pro. There's no lag in Premiere Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered a super-easy way to align perfectly.

1. Set your guides (if you're not aligning to just the edge of the frame)

   - You can either set up your guides manually or insert a grid that you want to align to. If you are just aligning to the edges then you can skip this step.
2. Select the clip you want to align first in your timeline
3. Then Click on the program monitor
4. Click View > Snap to Program Monitor
5. Then go back to the program monitor and double click on the frame you want to move and then click and drag and it'll automatically snap to an edge
6. Once you set your first frame you can also use that as your new edge to snap to for your next clip

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for our help! This worked out great.